# Completing geocoding before segueing to the next scene swift 3/xcode

Tags: swift

This is a fairly common topic and i've done my research but still just trying to get my head around closure/completion handlers.

I've got a scene where a location is entered. The user hits submit and there's a segue from submit to the next scene. I recognise the geocode is async but I want the geocode to complete in case there is an error before getting to the next scene.

There were a couple of short posts on this site but nothing substantive.

Below is my attempt at a completion handler which fails. I get the alert if there is an error but it first goes to the next scene before the alert pops.

```
func geocodeAddress (completion: @escaping () -> ()) {
    let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
    var coords: CLLocationCoordinate2D?

    address =  locationData(addressString)

    geoCoder.geocodeAddressString((address)!, completionHandler: {(placemarks: [CLPlacemark]?, error: Error?) -> Void in            
        if error != nil {
            self.alertGeocodeError()        
        }        
        if let placemark = placemarks?[0]{
            // Convert the address to a coordinate
            let location = placemark.location
            coords = location!.coordinate

            completion()
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "locationToConfirmSegue", sender: coords)           
            }    
        })    
    }

override func prepare (for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
    geocodeAddress{
        if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? ConfirmController {
            destinationVC.coords = sender as! CLLocationCoordinate2D
        }
     }   
 }
```

I don't quite get the @esaping either and any advice would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`prepare(for segue:)` is called automatically by the system once you call `self.performSegue`, so it you shouldn't call `geocodeAddress` inside `prepare(for segue:)`.

If you only need to segue from inside the completion handler of the geocoder, you don't need to return a closure from the `geocodeAddress` function, you can just call `performSegue` directly from it.

`completionHandlers` can be used to return values from asynchronous functions. Since geocoding is done on Apple's servers, it is an asynchronous function meaning that it doesn't return right away, but it takes a long time to execute hence the function returns before the execution would finish. The completion handler on the other hand is only called once execution actually finishes.

```
func geocodeAddress() {
    let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
    var coords: CLLocationCoordinate2D?

    address =  locationData(addressString)

    geoCoder.geocodeAddressString((address)!, completionHandler: {(placemarks: [CLPlacemark]?, error: Error?) -> Void in            
        if error != nil {
            self.alertGeocodeError()        
        }        
        if let placemark = placemarks?[0]{
            // Convert the address to a coordinate
            let location = placemark.location
            coords = location!.coordinate

            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "locationToConfirmSegue", sender: coords)           
        }    
    })    
}

override func prepare (for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
    if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? ConfirmController {
        destinationVC.coords = sender as! CLLocationCoordinate2D
    }
 }
```